# Can multiple trains use a bridge or tunnel at the same time?

Tags: openttd

Is there a setting to permit multiple trains in a tunnel or across a bridge at one time? I can't seem to find anything related to it, yet I would imagine with more complicated layouts this kind of setting would become essential.

If it is not possible, what are some tips/tricks to maximize crowded traffic through longer tunnels or bridges?

Comment: Do you mean more than one train going into the same direction or traveling in opposite directions?

Comment: @Denilson: I mean more than one train going in the same direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two relatively simple tricks you can use here:

1. Split the bridge/tunnel in twain, by digging a hole in the middle of the mountain or building a small island in the middle of the bay; big enough to place signals on.
2. Double (or triple) up on the bridge/tunnel in both directions.

For best results, combine both approaches, but do watch the money meter: both of these things can be pretty expensive.

Comment: +1 for 'twain'. I would have given you +2 for 'cleave' or 'hew', but alas.